# Convert pdf file to Excel in C#

Tags: c#, excel, pdf

I need to convert a pdf file to excel. I have tried to do this using  iTextSharp. I was able to extract lines using iTextSharp, but the problem is iTextSharp gives me spaces as column separator and so I am not able to bifurcate between column separator spaces and actual spaces in the data.

e.g. I have the following data in pdf (columns separated by :here),

*Col1:Col 2:Col 3:Col4*

I get,

*Col1 Col 2 Col 3 Col4*

I need to get something like
*Col1{tab}Col 2{tab}Col 3{tab}Col4*

Any solution for this?
I am also open to other C# libraries instead of iTextSharp , preferably open source.

Thanks

Comment: is the number of spaces always 1? or does it use extra spaces to make sure the text is aligned? Maybe it would be possible to detect [rivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/River_(typography)) in the text and replace them with tabs for your tables?

Comment: yes, the number of spaces is always 1. The source pdf data looks like a table , but I have no idea whether its actual format is a table or just text.